# Remove 'E' output headers from base64 string in TCPDF

Tags: php, base64, phpmailer, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF using

```
$base64String = $pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'E');
```

So I can send the data via AJAX

The only problem is that it comes with header information in addition to the Base64 string

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 name="FILE-31154d59f28c63efae86e4f3d6a00e13.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="FILE-31154d59f28c63efae86e4f3d6a00e13.pdf"
```

So if I take the string that is created to base64_decode() or use with phpMailer in my case it errors.  Is it possible to remove the headers so I only have the base64 string?

(The error is that the pdf can't be read by any PDF reader when opened)

I thought I'd be able to find something that solves this but I haven't found anything!!

UPDATE

This is what I've put in place to solve the issue

```
$base64String = preg_replace('/Content-[\s\S]+?;/', '', $base64String);
$base64String = preg_replace('/name=[\s\S]+?pdf"/', '', $base64String);
$base64String = preg_replace('/filename=[\s\S]+?"/', '', $base64String);
```

However it's not very elegant! So if anyone has a better solution please post it below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCPDF docs are huge but unusable – it's easier to [read the source code directly](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L7804). It has those extra headers *because you're asking for them* by using the `E` output mode, which is intended for generating email messages.

For sending the PDF data as a PHPMailer attachment, you want the straight binary PDF data as a string, as provided by the `S` output mode, which you can pass straight into [`addStringAttachment()`](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment), and PHPMailer will handle all the encoding for you. All you have to do is this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'S'), 'file.pdf');
```

To convert the PDF binary into base64, for example to us it in a JSON string, simply pass it through base64_encode:

```
$base64String = base64_encode($pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'S'));
```

Comment: Definitely helpful @Synchro but the 'S' out seems to output as FlateDecode instead of base64 and base64 is much easier to work with when sending post data as a var in an ajax call.  Again Thank you!

Comment: I think you are onto something with looking at the source code. Essentially I want this line https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L7801 to get returned and not the header info above it

Comment: But you asked how to use it as a PHPMailer attachment, not Ajax? Either way, use base64_encode on S mode output to get a json-compatible string.

Comment: that works with $base64String = base64_encode($pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'S')); for what I want it to do.  I had to use it in an if condition so I could use it for other outputs such as 'D' in my application, but you answered the question perfectly.  Could you update your answer to include this to help others :) :) very happy